# AWS Elastic Search Dashboard, Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-cognito

I have just setup open search and i cant access the dashboards. This is the access policy i have, but, its not working.
I have tried everything, please help this is driving me crazy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-2:655848079299:domain/elastic-search/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: kibana dashboard]

when i use "allow" as **Effect** i cant save it shows the following error

```
To protect domains with public access, a restrictive policy or fine-grained access control is required.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your policy there is `deny` everything.
Try to change it to `allow`.
Except of that there is more reasons that can cause `permission denied`

Comment: It gives me this error

"To protect domains with public access, a restrictive policy or fine-grained access control is required."